# Forked processes printing same time

Tags: c, time, fork

In the following code I don't understand why the forked processes (the ten of them) print the same time. As far as I understand it, each process should wait a random amount of time (up to 15 seconds) and then print the time as of their end. Can someone explain why they print the same time?

```
int main() {
    int x, i;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {   
        x = fork();
        if (x == 0) {
            sleep(rand() % 15);
            printf("%d ended: %ld\n", i, time(NULL));
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    while (wait(NULL) != -1);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: At the moment of the fork, they have the same seed.

Comment: Yep, see `srand()` and `rand()` documentation. It's not random numbers you get but a predetermined sequence.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Besides me forgetting to use srand(), I also forgot that computers run so fast that all processes run within the 1 sec period of time().

Comment: Also your code invokes undefined behaviour if `time_t` is not `long`. Read the documentation of functions you use!

Answer (score 3):

All the processes use the same seed value to generate the random numbers using `rand()`.

Man page of [rand()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html):

> If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is automatically seeded with a value of 1.

So `rand()` generates the same sequence of numbers because they're all seeded with the same value, C11, [7.22.2.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.2p2) says:

> The srand function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to rand. If srand is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated. If rand is called before any calls to srand have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand is first called with a seed value of 1.

You need to set a different seed value (by calling `srand()`) in different processes. For example, you can use `getpid()` in the child process to seed:

```
  if (x == 0) {
        srand((unsigned int)getpid());
        sleep(rand() % 15);
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, all processes are printing at the same time because they are all returning the same value for `rand`.

Each time the `rand` function is called, it performs some computation on the previous value that was returned to get the next value.  Before this function is called for the first time, it needs to be seeded with a starting value.  So given a particular seed value, `rand` will always return the same sequence of values.

The seed value is set with `srand`, however if you don't do this then the first call to `rand` effectively calls `srand(1)`.  So in your case, each process calls `rand` for the first time with an implicit seed of 1.  As a result, each process returns the same value.

You can get around this by generating the random sleep times in the parent process.  That way, each value used by the child processes will be different.  Also, while it's not the cause of your issue, you should also explicitly call `srand`:

```
int main() {
    int x, i;

    srand(time(NULL) ^ getpid());
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        int sleep_time = rand() % 15;  // generate random number in parent
        x = fork();
        if (x == 0) {
            sleep(sleep_time);
            printf("%d ended: %ld\n", i, time(NULL));
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    while (wait(NULL) != -1);

    exit(0);
}
```